# How to export data by date to csv using angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I am trying to export the data I have using material button in angular 11 first here is code for exportdata without any date element which just works fine.

```
downloadCSV() {
    // subscribing the data from the url in exportData function 
    this.dataSvc.exportData().subscribe(data => {
      this.export = data
      //variable
      let jsonArrayObject = [];
      //looping through the array of objects
      for (let i = 0; i < this.export['data'].length; i++) {
        jsonArrayObject.push(this.export['data'][i]);
        // console.log(jsonArrayObject);
      }
      ///this.dtHolidays : JSONDATA , HolidayList : CSV file Name, this.csvOptions : file options
      new AngularCsv(jsonArrayObject, "ExgenReceipts", this.csvOptions);

    })
```

and now if I add datepicker and I have start and end date and data should be exported between these two any Idea what I should be doing ?

```
downloadCSVByDate() {
    // popup date picker

    // subscribing the data from the url in exportDataByDate function 
    this.dataSvc.exportDataByDate().subscribe(data => {
      this.export = data
      //variable
      let jsonArrayObject = [];
      //looping through the array of objects
      for (let i = 0; i < this.export['data'].length; i++) {
        jsonArrayObject.push(this.export['data'][i]);
        // console.log(jsonArrayObject);
      }
      ///this.dtHolidays : JSONDATA , HolidayList : CSV file Name, this.csvOptions : file options
      new AngularCsv(jsonArrayObject, "ExgenReceipts", this.csvOptions);

    })
```

[image: CLick here for UI]

Looking for someone to help me in this new to angular

Comment: explicit how you want your datepicker interact with your export

Comment: Like I am not sure how should I explicit it as I just want it to go as if only the data between start and end should be exported I have php api which does it on the backend I have to pass those strings of start and end date actually.

Comment: maybe you can call the same code as the `this.dataSvc.exportDataByDate()` but when the date picker is updated, we totally don't know what do you use as date picker